# Echo does not show up a picture

Tags: php, echo

Okay i have a site wich makes signatures. But because some header problems i had to put it in another file and use echo. this is the code:

```
<h1>Create your European Trucking signatures</h1>
<?php
echo '<img src="SigGen.php?player=$Playername&score=$Score&money=$Money" />';
?>
</div>
```

But it shows a broken image thingy. But when i go to the SigGen.php itself it does show up like here:
http://european-trucking.com/SigGen.php?player_name=Thimo
This is the code of SigGen:

```
<?  
/* 
***Made by: Nodroz*** 
*** Enjoy your signatures! *** 
*/ 

$username="10528_Thimo"; //Your MySQL Username. 
$password="*********"; // Your MySQL Pass. 
$database="10528_Thimo"; // Your MySQL database. 
$host="95.211.***.***"; // Your MySQL host. This is "localhost" or the IP specified by your hosting company. 

$player_name=$_GET['player_name']; // This gets the player his name from the previous page. 

/* Next, we will make a connection to the mysql.  
If it can't connect, it'll print on the screen: Unable to select database. Be sure the databasename exists and online is. */ 

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password); // Connection to the database. 
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database. Be sure the databasename exists and online is."); //Selection of the database. If it can't read the database, it'll give an error. 

/* To protect MySQL injection. */ 
$player_name = stripslashes($player_name); 
$player_name = mysql_real_escape_string($player_name); 



$query="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name='$player_name'"; // Gets all the information about the player. 
$result=mysql_query($query); 
$i=mysql_num_rows($result); // Here we are counting how many rows this result gives us. 

/* We will now put the player's information into variables so we can use them more easily. */ 
/* DON'T FORGET: The names should be exact the same as in your mysql db.*/ 

if ($i == 1) // If the user has been correct, then it'll give us 1 row. If its 1 row, then it'll proceed with the code. 
{ 

    $Playername=mysql_result($result,0,"Name"); // Gets the username of the player and put it in the variable $Playername. 
    $Money=mysql_result($result,0,"Money"); // Gets the money of the player and put it in the variable $Money. 
    $Score=mysql_result($result,0,"Score"); // Gets the score of the player and put it in the variable $Score. 


    // Creating of the .png image.  
    header('Content-Type: image/png;'); // Don't touch this. We use this to tell the script we're working with an image. 
    $im = @imagecreatefrompng('PlayerSig.png') or die("Cannot select the correct image. Please contact the webmaster."); // Don't forget to put your picture there. Eg: playersig.png 
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 000,000,000); // RED, GREEN, BLUE --> Go to www.colorpicker.com, select a nice color, copy the R/G/B letters provided by colorpicker and put them here. 
    $text_username = "$Playername"; // This gets the information: player name to be showed in the picture. 
    $text_score = "$Score"; // Same as above but with score. 
    $text_money = "$Money"; // Same as above but with money. 
    $font = 'myfont.ttf'; //Upload your custom font to the directory where this file is placed. Then change the name here. 
    /* USAGE OF THE imagettftext: First ($im) shouldn't be changed. (16) is the text-size. (0) is the angle of your text. Change it, and you'll see what's going on. (20) is de X-coordinate of the text. 
    (36) is the Y-coordinate of the text. */ 
    imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 5, 20, $text_color, $font, $text_username); // Prints the username in the picture.  
    imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 5, 40, $text_color, $font, "Score:");
    imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 72, 40, $text_color, $font, $text_score); // Prints the score in the picture. 
    imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 5, 60, $text_color, $font, "Money:");
    imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 72, 60, $text_color, $font, $text_money); // Prints the money in the picture. 
    imagepng($im); 
    imagedestroy($im);  
} else echo('Username is not in our database. Please try again.'); // If the username doesn't exist (so the row is 0) then it'll give en error. 

mysql_close(); 

?>
```

Anyone knows why it doesnt show up as an image using echo?

Comment: Probably because something is wrong. Try viewing it directly.

Comment: Directly you are using `player_name` as GET-parameter while the 'include' is using `player`...?

Comment: As i said the picture works if i go directly there: http://european-trucking.com/SigGen.php?player_name=Thimo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think the problem is that you cant use variable names in string like this :

THIS WONT WORK

```
echo 'Hi $userName';
```

THIS WILL WORK

```
echo "Hi $userName";
```

so your line :

```
echo '<img src="SigGen.php?player=$Playername&score=$Score&money=$Money" />';
```

needs to be changed to :

```
echo "<img src='SigGen.php?player=$Playername&score=$Score&money=$Money' />";
```

Comment: http://european-trucking.com/signature.php?player_name=Thimo The picture is broken. It shows a broken picture thingy. Or does it work for you?

Comment: Well it shows a broken image link beneath Create your European Trucking signatures.

Comment: In mozilla firefox it doesnt show a broken thingy its just blank O_o

Comment: this is the source from you site :<img src="SigGen.php?player=&score=&money=">

this is on the HTML source after the php code generated a html page, looks like your variables are empty

Comment: I have this: <?php
    echo "<img src='SigGen.php?player=$Playername&score=$Score&money=$Money' />";
    ?>

Comment: $Playername , $Score , $Money are variables , seems like they are empty, check your code where do they get data from

Comment: This is the form:
 <form action="signature.php" method="get"> <!-- When you click the "send" button, this information will be send to the "signature.php" page. If you're using another php page, you need to change "signature.php" to the file you called it. -->
        Playername: <input type="text" name="player_name"><br>  <!-- This is a little text box which will ask for you playername. -->
       <input type="Submit"> <!-- A "send" button. -->
       </form>

Comment: Finally fixed it! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<?php echo '<img src="SigGen.php?player='.$Playername.'&score='.$Score.'&money='.$Money.'" />'; ?>
```

use the concatenation features of the echo to properly append the variables to the image link

Comment: I just found out that the strings are just empty

Comment: Also normally it does not send the score and money but only the name.